How to solve this 3-dimensional wave equation?
Consider $\square u=0$ in $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}^3$, with $u(0, x)=\mathbb{1}_{B_R}$ and $\partial_t u(0, x)=0$. I want to find the solution $u(t, x)$ explicitly.here $\square u=u_{tt}-\Delta u$, I want to use kirchoff formula, which is 
Kirchhoff's formula:Consider the initial-value problem for the wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^3$ :
$$
u_{tt}-\Delta u=0, u=u(x, t), x \in \mathbb{R}^3, t>0 \quad u(x, 0)=u_0(x), u_t(x, 0)=u_1(x) .
$$
The solution is:
$u(x, t)=t \times$ average value of $u_1$ over $S_t(x)+\frac{d}{d t}\left[t \times\right.$ average value of $u_0$ over $\left.S_t(x)\right]$
Here $S_t(x)=\left\{y \in \mathbb{R}^3 ;|y-x|=t\right\}$ is the surface of the sphere with center $x$, radius $t$. This may also be written as:
$$
u(x, t)=\frac{1}{4 \pi t} \int_{S_t(x)} u_1(y) d A(y)+\frac{d}{d t}\left[\frac{1}{4 \pi t} \int_{S_t(x)} u_0(y) d A(y)\right] .
$$
in this problem, $u_{0}=1_{B(R)}$ and $u_1=0$ , I notice that while $t$ grows gradually, the ball ${y||y-x|=t}$ and $B(R)$(the latter ball is a ball centered at $0$ with radius $R$) has partial part coincide, but I don't know how to treat this

The problem is unclear. What is wrong with Kirchoff's formula?

I want to solve it at case $u(0, x)=\mathbb{1}_{B_R}$ and $\partial_t u(0, x)=0$ @K.defaoite

So.... plug them into the formula? The first integral is just zero which simplifies your calculations.

the second integral's region is $|y-x|<t$, in this case, this ball is not centered at $0$, hence I don't know how to treat the overlapped region @K.defaoite

oh, i understand. Is a closed form really useful to you? Why not just compute the integrals numerically?

The scalar radial wave equation in $\mathbb R_+(t) \times \mathbb R^3(\mathbf x) $ in spherical coordinates, separated
$$  a''(t) \  b(r) - a(t) \ \left( b''(2)- \frac{2}{r}\ b'(r) \right) = 0$$
has particular solutions
$$u_k(r,t) =\frac{1}{r} \left( c_1 \ e^{i\ k \ (t - r) } + c_2 \ e^{i \ k \ (t + r) } \right)$$ $$v_k(r,t)= \partial_t u_k(r,t) =\frac{1}{r} \left( i\ c_1 k \ e^{i\ k \ (t - r) } + i\ c_2 \ k \ e^{i \ l \ (t + r) } \right)$$
The start conditions for $u(0,r) , v(0,r)$ have to be represented by Fourier integrals
$$\int_0^\infty( c_1(k)e^{k\ r} +  c_2(k)e^{-k\ r} ) dk = r \ u(0,r) $$
$$\int_0^ \infty( c_1(k) \ i \ k \ e^{k\ r} + c_2(k) \ i \ k \ e^{-k\ r} ) dk = r \ v(0,r) $$
By an incidental cancellation of exponents of $r$ in $\mathbb R^1, \mu =dr $ and $\mathbb R^3, \mu = dr \ r^2 $,  the Fourier transform reduces to simple integrals with Lebesgue measure and easy exponentials as basis in $\mathit L_1(\mathbb R_+)$ . Mirror principles can be used to impose boundary conditions at $r=0$,  typically $\partial_r u(t,r=0) =0$ in order to get smooth solutions.
